# How do I set a launch image for Xamarin Studio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to follow https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS/hello,iOS_quickstart/. But on Step 26, I don't know what to do. What it shows in the image there is not what it looks like in Xamarin Studio Community (6.1.5 build 0). Instead it looks like [image: this]. Can someone help translate between what the tutorial says and what I'm seeing? I'm brand new to Xamarin, although I've been a C# developer for a long time.

Step 26 shows a screen shot like this [image: this].

Comment: Did you migrate to an asset catalog?

Comment: I did click on a button that said something about an asset catalog. I couldn't figure out how to undo that so I could show better reproduction steps.

Comment: To be clear though it never looked anything like the guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like our guide there needs an update to bring it in line with current practices - I'll pass this feedback to the team.

These days, defining launch images in the `Info.plist` is deprecated and it is recommended that developers use either Asset Catalogs or Launch Storyboards - the latter being the most recent and suggested option.

More information on Launch Screens can be found here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/

Managing with asset catalogs:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/deprecated/launch-screens/#asset-catalogs

Comment: Perfect thanks. I'll take a look at that. Thanks for the quick help.